# How do I Force Google Maps Links to Open the Google Maps App on iOS6?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, google-maps, maps

In the past (iOS5 and earlier) clicking on a link for directions within a website opened the separate maps app and provided directions. How do I force links in websites, that would normally open a google maps link in a "desktop" web browser, to open the new external google maps app? I do not find the current google maps website adequate (can't figure out how it would provide dynamic (voice) directions) and the new apple maps app is not opened by those links.

Comment: Each time you arrive on the Google Maps site it asks if you want to open the Google Map App.

Answer (score 1):

As Matthieu Riegler said, when you go to the Google maps site you will be prompted to launch the app. Unfortunately, there is no way to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe at this point, Google Maps correctly implements deep links. So if you open a maps.google.com link, [like this one](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Eiffel+Tower/@48.8583701,2.2922873,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47e66e2964e34e2d:0x8ddca9ee380ef7e0!8m2!3d48.8583701!4d2.2944813?shorturl=1) it'll open directly in Google Maps, if you have it installed. It even works with Google Maps shortlinks, (the ones starting with `https://goo.gl/` [like this](https://goo.gl/maps/qrYFcQmKGs9ff8ni8). This all works in both Chrome and Safari.